# Search in an arraylist by keywords

Tags: java, list, arraylist

How can I search an arraylist on Java by a keyword in a way that it returns me all of the objects attributes?

For example, I have a List called Employee, that has a code, name and salary. I would like to get its salary and code searching by his Name. How can I do that? Thank you

Comment: Do you know how to use a loop to iterate over your array list?  and do you know how to check if one employee's name is the same as the keyword name?  and do you know how to return an object from a function?  If you know these 3 things, you can solve your problem yourelf.

Comment: I don't. I'm just starting on Java @SamIam

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you do it.

1. Use a `for` loop to iterate over your `ArrayList` of `Employee`s.
2. inside that `for` loop, check to see if the current `Employee`'s name is equal to the name you're searching for.
3. If the names are equal, then return that `Employee`

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to create an Employee class that contains an ArrayList of code, name and salary with getters / setters? That way, in your ArrayList, you can just store Employee objects, and in a for loop, you can use, for instance `if(currentEmployeeObject.getSalary == 55000){}` in a for loop that iterates over every item in that ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

This is a method that returns the first employee with the name in the list `employees`.

```
//gets an Employee from the list
public Employee getEmployeeByNameAndRemove(String name){ 
    ArrayList<Employee> employees; //this is where you'd get your list of employees

    for(int i = 0; i < employees.size(); i++){
        Employee dude = employees.get(i);
        if(dude.getName().equals(name)){
            employees.remove(i);
            return dude;
        }
    }
}
```

This is how you call the method.

```
Employee dude = getEmployeeByNameAndRemove("Johnson");
int ID = dude.getID();
int salary = dude.getSalary();
```

assuming that you have the methods `getID()` and `getSalary()` in your class `Employee`.

Comment: What if the employees list was in another class? 
I can't initialize Employee dude : dude.employees @Kyranstar

Comment: Ok. How could I get his ID and salary now? @Kyranstar

Comment: And how could I remove the object by his name? @Kyranstar